# Windows (in older SSD) crashes after installing new SSD to an empty slot

Tags: ssd

I recently added the new NVME SSD in my additional slot of Nitro 5 AN515-55. windows boots normally at first but after 5 min of usages it freezes at one point, and I need to force shutdown. i am also getting 2 windows boot manager option in booting option. how can I solve this? is it the problem of SSD or anything else? p.s:-my pc has 2 nvme/sata ports

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tested the new drive? Does it work fine without the new drive? Do both boot options show when the drive is disconnected? Have you updated drivers and firmware?